# Can I use Sysinternals Process Monitor to monitor a specific registry value?

Tags: procmon, windows-registry

Something somewhere is modifying a value in a registry key, and I want to track it down.

I thought I might set up ProcMon to watch that value, but as far as I can tell, it only filters to keys. There is far too much noise for me at that level.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is filter on the `RegSetValue` operation as well as filtering the `Path` to match the registry key you want to monitor.

[image]